# Set time on x axis of jfreechart

Tags: java, jsp, jfreechart

I am using jfreeChart and i want to show hours(in 24 hours format) on x axis of chart

Is there any library or class that can help me to plot hours on chart ?

Comment: you should use XYDataSet. check here for example http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/AtimeserieschartrepresentingdatafromanXYDatasettheverticalaxishasalogarithmicscale.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart*. Dataset provided to this method take the series of type *TimeSeries*. Constructor of *TimeSeries* take the argument of [time period](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/package-summary.html)
Use *Hour* class for generating the chart for hourly data. In series, add time of the (date+hour) and data for plotting